# Is there a way to use fs to add data to json object

Tags: node.js, json, fs

i have a question about something i wanna do with fs, its updating a pice of data inside a json object so like

```
"links": ["https://google.com/", "https://youtube.com/"]
}
```

Then after youtube i could write a program that i can use to add another link inside the the links object. So say i wanted to add instagram to the list i would run that program instead. (this is in the sence of that im working on a discord bot so it would add the arguments to the list but you get the point) Is this possible somehow? Kinda like a update where it just adds another link.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the question completely. But I assume you have a file that you have json inside and you want to add data to an array. I would just read the file, parse the json, push another item in to the array and then overwrite the whole file with the updated data.

Comment: Exactly what i want, i have a json consisting of alot of links and i want to make it so i can add a link just by using for example fs

Answer (score 0):

For example the json is in a file called `youtube-links.json`

First we read the data like so `const readFile = fs.readFileSync('youtube-links.json')`

Convert to string `const cleanData = readFile.toString()`

Then parse the JSON file `const linksFromFIle = JSON.parse(cleanData)`

After that we push new data to it

```
 linksFRomFIle.push({

     links: ["new string"]

 })

Then save the new file by overwriting it with the new data
```

Comment: Thanks this consept is just something i came up with on the go so ill try something like it when im home